# How to Stop FCM Notification in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem in FCM. I had added FCM in my Android application through the server API. Now I want to stop the notification messages on a single device. This privilege is in the hands of the user who use my app. But I don't know how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you should be handling this kind of concern on your app server. Have you at the very least tried something? Since describing what you want to do and saying you don't know how to do it is like asking for codes itself.

Comment: This is rather broad when you look at it.. Not much details provided.. However, if you're using Topics, you can simply have the user unsubscribed..

Answer (score 0):

You must be tagging the device registration Id  with some user id of that particular user at your backend. So while sending the notification from api you can check for that particular user before sending the notification.

Comment: i have one doubt when the app is in background on that time how i can manage the notification an how it works. please describe or give some example

Comment: So are you saying that you want to send the notification only if that app is in background but not when the app is running on foreground?

Comment: If that is the scenario then you need to manage it from native app code itself. Because your api can not determine if your app is running on foreground or background on any device. or as an other solution you need to manage some flag at server end which shall be updated by the app as soon as it will go to background or coming to front end but for that as well you need to write some code in the native application.

Comment: It's really simple: In your `Service` which receives the messages just check if any of your `Activities` are open and if they are not display the notification, otherwise ignore the message. I don't understand what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I think xaver he wants to do that only for a specific user, that is what i understand from his problem description.